# How to avoid nested "with" statements when working with multiple files in Python

Tags: python, file, design-patterns, refactoring

When working with multiple files in Python code can get ugly when using the recommended style:

```
with open("foo.txt") as foo:
    with open("bar.txt", "w") as bar:
         with open("baz.txt", "w") as baz:
              # Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
```

That's three indentation levels just for working with files! The alternative would be this

```
foo = open("foo.txt")
bar = open("bar.txt", "w")
baz = open("baz.txt", "w")
# Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
foo.close()
bar.close()
baz.close()
```

I have a feeling that either of these examples could be refactored to something more elegant. Any examples?

Comment: `with open('file1.txt') as f1, open('file2.txt') as f2:` do like this.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python 2.7 and up let you specify multiple context managers in one `with` statement:

```
with open("foo.txt") as foo, open("bar.txt", "w") as bar, open("baz.txt", "w") as baz:
    # Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
```

The line *does* get long, and you cannot use parentheses to keep that below 80 characters. You can use `\` backslash continuations however:

```
with open("foo.txt") as foo,\
        open("bar.txt", "w") as bar,\
        open("baz.txt", "w") as baz:
    # Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
```

Or you could place newlines inside the parentheses of the ‘open()` calls:

```
with open(
    "foo.txt"
) as foo, open(
    "bar.txt", "w"
) as bar, open(
    "baz.txt", "w"
) as baz:
    # Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
```

Starting Python 3.10, this has been made easier still with addition of [parentheses support for multi-item context managers](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with (
    open("foo.txt") as foo,
    open("bar.txt", "w") as bar,
    open("baz.txt", "w") as baz,
):
    # Read from foo, write different output to bar an baz
```

Another option would be to use [`contextlib.ExitStack()` context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) (only in Python 3.3 and up):

```
from contextlib import ExitStack

with ExitStack() as stack:
    foo = stack.enter_context(open("foo.txt"))
    bar = stack.enter_context(open("bar.txt"))
    baz = stack.enter_context(open("baz.txt"))
```