# Python: How to handle nested with statement for multiple opened files

Tags: python, python-3.x, with-statement

I have lets say 10 files that needs to be opened and worked at the same time.

```
files  = ['example1', 'example2', 'example3', ... 'example10']
```

Currently I do this

```
with open('example1', 'w') as example1:
    
    .
      .
        .

        with open('example10', 'w') as example10:
            # working with all files the same time
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid nested “with” statements when working with multiple files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26731720/how-to-avoid-nested-with-statements-when-working-with-multiple-files-in-python?rq=1)

Comment: This is pretty much the use case for an [`ExitStack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack); the documentation uses a list of files to open as an example.